# How to create a completely flexible piano keyboard with HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html, flexbox, css-shapes, piano

I'm trying to create a piano keyboard that will keep its elements ratios using flex box, but can't seem to make the black notes stay the same width or height once I start changing the window size.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimrodsarda/924sefae/)

```
body{
width: 800px;
height: 200px;
display: flex;
}

#kbd {

padding: 1%;
flex-flow: column;
display: flex;
flex: 4;
}

#keys {
display: flex;
flex: 8;
justify-content: center;
}


.note {
flex: 1;
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
}

.black {
justify-content: center;
position: absolute;
height: 45%;
background-color: #474747;
color: white;
width: 8%;
margin: 0 -4%; 
}

.white {
flex-flow: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
outline: 2px solid #474747;
color: #474747;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

Comment: please include the code in the question itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percentage height is calculated based on the height of the first positioned parent. In this case, the `#keys` and `#kbd` divs don't have a `position` CSS rule. This means the black keys are scaled based on the width of the body, instead of their direct parent.

Add `position: relative;` to the `#keys` div to make it work properly.

Answer (score 5):

## [Demo @ Codepen](https://codepen.io/enteleform/pen/PepqYV)

---

Flexbox is not required for this. A responsive keyboard layout can be accomplished with:

- additional class selectors that correspond with the note of each key:

```html
<div class="key white c"      ></div>
<div class="key black c_sharp"></div>
<div class="key white d"      ></div>
<div class="key black d_sharp"></div>
<div class="key white e"      ></div>
<div class="key white f"      ></div>
<div class="key black f_sharp"></div>
<div class="key white g"      ></div>
<div class="key black g_sharp"></div>
<div class="key white a"      ></div>
<div class="key black a_sharp"></div>
<div class="key white b"      ></div>
```

- a margin for all black keys & each white key which precedes a black key, using an offset based on the black key's size:

```css
.a, .b, .d, .e, .g, .black{
  margin: 0 0 0 (-($blackKey_Width / 2) - $blackKey_BorderWidth);
}
```

- the following key placement attributes:

```css
.key{
  float:    left;
  position: relative;
}
```

- a higher `z-index` for the black keys:

```css
.white{
  z-index: 1;
}
.black{
  z-index: 2;
}
```

- [**Viewport Units**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) [`vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax`] for the (`height` & `width`) attributes of the (`.white` & `.black`) selectors. You can make this even more dynamic by sizing the black keys as a percentage of the white keys.

Comment: Your CSS piano is so well done, probably one of the best I've seen. Would you mind if I used your CSS code in a React project I'm working on? I would be happy to attribute you.

Comment: @damon Thanks, glad you found it useful! Feel free to use it in your project.

Answer (score 2):

The position should be relative rather than absolute.
Also you should set both the height of the containing divs to 100%.

Refer to the Fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/924sefae/6/

```
#kbd {
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
#kbd {
  height: 100%;
  ...
}

.black {
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you need your black keys to be independent blocks but here is an example

```
<body>
   <div class="note-container">
     <div class="white-note black-note"></div> 
     <div class="white-note black-note"></div>
     <div class="white-note"></div> 
     <div class="white-note black-note"></div>
     <div class="white-note black-note"></div> 
     <div class="white-note black-note"></div>
     <div class="white-note"></div> 
     <div class="white-note black-note"></div>
     <div class="white-note black-note"></div> 
     <div class="white-note"></div>
   </div>  
</body>

body {
  background: #000;
}

.note-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.white-note {
  position: relative;
  width: 10%;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.white-note.black-note:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: that :after trick is very helpful! <3

Comment: It sure is, the issue is that `after` and `before` cannot be binded to events, i hope in near feature it can be achieved...